# How to display a full color image with XCB or X11?

Tags: linux, image, x11, xcb

I can load a PNG image into memory and get the raw pixel data from that using libpng, and I can also create windows with a blank background using XCB or plain X11.

What should I do next to display an image inside a window?

Comment: xcb is an X11 client library. Everything xcb does *is* X11. Perhaps you mean "xcb or Xlib"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XLib method is as follows:

- Create an `XImage` structure with depth appropriate to your visual
- Convert raw pixel data to the format corresponding to the combination of depth and visual-class you have
- call `XPutImage`

The second step can be achieved by calling `XPutPixel` for each individual pixel. You will have to convert RGB values to pixel values. For 15,- 16,- 24- or 32-bit visuals this is a trivial manipulation with bitmasks (use `visual->red_mask` to determine where to put the red component, etc). If you want to support 8-bit depth you have to use dithering, and allocate and use an appropriate colormap, probably a 216-element colour cube. Fortunately 8-bit-only hardware is rare these days.

If calling `XPutPixel` is too slow for you, you will have to implement what it does in line. Use e.g. [this source](http://cr.yp.to/2004-494/libpng/libpng-1.2.5/contrib/gregbook/rpng-x.c) for guidance.

xcb has a library called xcb-util-image with the functionality parallel to that of XImage. I'm not familiar with it.